# Comparing two columns with ID

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am comparing two columns A and B. 
The columns A and B contains the ID from a Database.

The ID is 13 digits long, but most of the cases they are 11 digits long.

1. Case 1: If column A has an ID ABC02369000 and column B has an ID ABC02369000 the result is match.
2. Case 2: If column A has an ID ABC14285500 and column B has an ID ABC1428550000 the result is still match.
3. Case 3: If column A has an ID ABC15184200 and column B has an ID ABC15144200 the result is no match.

I would like to have a code for this criteria. If it is matched, then highlighted as green, else as red.

I have tried conditional formatting already. I would be glad, if I can have it in code.

```
Sub RangeTest()
    Dim targetWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim totalrows As Integer

    For i = 2 To 112
        Set targetWorksheet = Worksheets("Preparation sheet")
        With targetWorksheet
            Cells(i, 3) = IIf(Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i, 2), "Yes", "NO")
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = IIf(Cells(i, 3) = "Yes", RGB(0, 255, 0), RGB(255, 0, 0))
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RangeTest()

Dim targetWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim totalrows As Integer

For i = 2 To 112
    Set targetWorksheet = Worksheets("Preparation sheet")
    With targetWorksheet
        If Left(.Cells(i, 1), 11) = Left(.Cells(i, 2), 11) Then
            .Cells(i, 3) = "Yes"
            .Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        Else
            .Cells(i, 3) = "NO"
            .Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You could use the same `LEFT` approach in conditional formatting also.

Comment: I read `I have tried conditional formatting already` as tried but failed.  No worries.